# ASP.NET MVC: Passing 2D array from Controller to View

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have a 2D array in the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Home()
 {
       string[][] a = new string[250][];

       for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
       {
            a[x] = new string[2];
            a[x][0] = b[x]; 
            a[x][1] = b[x];
       }

       return View();
 }
```

where "b" is a 1D array with the same length as "a".

How do I pass the 2D array "a" into the JavaScript in the view?

Comment: This is not a 2d array, its a jagged array (an array of arrays), a 2d array is defined as 'string [,]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself through trial and error. Seems like JavaScript can in fact interpret 2D Arrays from C# when serialized through Json.

In controller:

```
for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
{
                a[x] = new string[2];
                a[x][0] = b[x];
                a[x][1] = b[x];
}

ViewBag.a = a;
```

In view:

```
var a2 =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.a));
alert("First value of first term: " + a2[0][0] + "Second value of first term: " + a2[0][1]);
```